# javafx - Custom Control - How to handle text events and apply predicates generically. (got stuck in middle)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

This is updated version of the question [javafx-TableView as combobox popup (Tried and able to achieve partially. need help further)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372780/javafx-tableview-as-combobox-popup-tried-and-able-to-achieve-partially-need-he)

Based on few inputs I got here and referred some existing custom controls (controlsFX), I started implementing my custom control and achieved most of it but got stuck in middle. So need your support.

**I have attached my whole project [here](https://app.box.com/s/dfmu9kajazhc00pnbtgm0d9gn1lr4wq3) for reference.**

Let me explain my requirement first.

My real application consists of around 40 to 50 text fields in the scene. Suggesstions should be poped up, based of the text typed by the user in the text fields and user should select something using keyboard and able to tab out to the next text field. The suggesstion popup should be a table view with 2 or more columns. The search can be applied on any 1 column or all columns which should be configured by the user while instantiating the control. Please see the screen shot for your reference.
[image]

***Now what I have achieved.***

I have created a CustomControl with 2 classess which will show a popup with a table view inside below the configured node.

```
**TableViewPopup.java extends PopupControl
TableViewPopupSkin.java implements Skin<TableViewPopup<T>>**
```

refering `AutoCompletePopup.java and AutoCompletePopupSkin.java` from controlsFX project.
This is working as expected (atleast most of the functionalities).

Then I should be able to attach the TableViewPopup to a TextField.

So I created another CustomControl with 2 classess

```
SearchableTextField.java extends TextField
SearchableTextFieldSkin.java extends TextFieldSkin
```

So this is the control user will add it to their scene finally and tell this control what tableviewpopup should be displayed when the text changes.
Till here everything works fine.

***Where I got stuck or what I want to do?***

```
<SearchableTextField fx:id="personSearchableTextField" referenceDataControlNameToLoad="/view/PersonReferenceDataTableView" />
<SearchableTextField fx:id="vehicleSearchableTextField" referenceDataControlNameToLoad="/view/VehicleReferenceDataTableView" />
```

In the above code snippet, I have 2 instances of my SearchableTextField each shows 2 different TableViewPopup(one with Person and other with Vehicle).

Now I want to apply different predicates to the tableview's filtered list as the user started typing in the text field.
I have attached a textChangedListener which is inside the SearchableTextFieldSkin class. First of all I dont know how to get the filtered list inside the textChangedListener (Please advice is there any better way.) but somehow I'm referring the filtered list but dont know how to apply the predicates bcoz it may be any different enitties (in my case it may be Person entity or Vehicle entity). 
I dont want to check the instances hard coded bcoz in my real application i have around 150 entities.

I also dont want the predicates related logic inside the SearchableTextFieldSkin class. means, i want all my different predicates in a separate file and just want to call them.

Or atleast somehow route the filtering logic from the SearchableTextFieldSkin class.

Please suggest a way and a better way. I really concerened about performance bcoz what i am doing is a c# with dev express components project that i am currently rewriting in java using javafx bcoz the performance is worse like anything in c#.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Guys, Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

I would be trying to keep the Predicates close to, or inside, the controller that needs to use them. PersonController should deal with Person predicates, VehicleController with the Vehicles ones, and also with any logic for deciding which fields are searched etc.

There are a few ways to do what I'm thinking, but they all boil down to passing the search field text back through to the `IGenericReferenceDataController` implementation, which resets the `Predicate` on the `FilteredList`.

You could expose a `StringProperty` on `IGenericReferenceDataController` to track the filter text. A helper class that encapsulates the `FilteredList` and the `Predicates` for a particular controller, exposes the filterText property and handles the logic for resetting it would be better as that should be fairly generic code that you can plug into the `IGenericReferenceDataController` keeping it all isolated. Something along the lines of:

```
public interface FilterHelper {
    public StringProperty filterTextProperty();
    // any methods to assign filters for columns etc. such as
    public void assignCurrentFilter(...);
    ... etc ...
}
```

Then get `IGenericReferenceDataController` to expose it's instance of this class:

```
public interface IGenericReferenceDataController extends IGenericController {
    public FilteredList<?> getInnerTableViewControlDataSource();
    public FilterHelper getFilterHelper();
}
```

You would need to pass that out through `TableViewPopupSkin` and `TableViewPopup` until it finally gets to `SearchableTextFieldSkin` where you can have:

```
private void registerListeners() {
    tableViewPopup.getFilterHelper().filterTextProperty().bind(sourceSearchableTextField.textProperty());
    ...
}
```

Your FilterHelper implementation then handles resetting the filter on the list every time the search text changes and SearchableTextField knows nothing.

If there is a faster way to get from SearchableTextFieldSkin to IGenericReferenceDataController you could cut out some of the intermediary methods that just pass the reference along, but I couldn't see any in your code and I don't use fxml so I have no idea what magic might be possible there.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Actually i was waiting for some replay from anyone.  Let me try applying. Will update you soon. Thanks again!